# Incorrect precedence when saving notebook as Wolfram language package

Tags: notebooks, packages

I want to save a notebook as a Wolfram language package. When I use the menu command `File>Save As` and choose ".wl" then the resulting package contains precedence issues which were not there in the original notebook file.
For example, a code which is correctly interpreted as `(a^2).b` in the notebook becomes `(a^2.)*b` in the package.

Example: A notebook which calculates `(a^2).b`

```
nb=CreateDocument[];
NotebookWrite[nb,Cell[BoxData[RowBox[{SuperscriptBox["a","2"],".","b"}]],"Code"]]
```

Use `File>Save As` and choose Wolfram language package.
Resulting package looks as follows:

```
(* ::Package:: *)

a^2.b
```

This package evaluates `(a^2.)*b` instead of `(a^2).b`.

Is there a possibility to save a notebook as a Wolfram language package preserving correct precedence?

Edit: Mathematica version used in the test:

```
$Version
(* 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019) *)
```

Comment: What version are you using, I see `a^2 . b` in the package, notice spaces, which evaluates correctly.

Comment: I have this issue in v12.0.0. It happens when using`File>Save As` for the whole notebook, but not when doing `ExportString[..., "Package"]` of a single expression. It also happens when copy-pasting the expression into another text editor.

Comment: I get `a^2 . b` in the package as expected when using `File > Save As` for the whole notebook (*Mathematica* 12.3.1 on Windows 10 x64).